# Launch External Process With Time To Live

Tags: c#

I need to launch an external process, that at times, will lock up. I have no control over this process. I'm looking for a way to launch an external process in c#, killing it if it takes over N seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
// configure psi here - FileName, UseShellExecute etc.
Process p = Process.Start(psi);
if (!p.WaitForExit(N * 1000)) // time in millisecs 
    p.Kill(); // terminate with extreme prejudice
```

Comment: It'd be better to try to Close() the process prior to calling Kill() - if the process is handling messages still, it gives it a chance to shut down gracefully.

Comment: True, though of course it may not have a message loop. But I thought it was `CloseMainWindow` which does the "please quit now" - and `Close` just Disposes of any resources this process has about the other one.

Comment: Oh yeah, it is... I'll fix my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle this is to use Process.Start to start your process, and setup a timer to watch it.

If the process is still running after N sections, call [Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) followed by  [Process.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx).  The docs for Process.Close actually show closing a process after 10 seconds.

One thing, though - if the process is truly "locked up", Close may not actually shut down the process.  In that case, you may want to wait and then call [Process.Kill.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)  This is a hard-kill of the process, though, so I'd recommend it as a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    Process x = new Process();
    x.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    x.Start();
    //wait 10 sec, then kill process
    x.WaitForExit(10000);
    if (!x.HasExited) {
        x.Kill();
    }
}
```